# How to test if a USB A cable is an active or passive cable?

Tags: usb, cable

From my understanding active USB type A cables boost the signal they receive with electronics inside of them.

Without taking them apart, is there a reliable way to test if a given USB type A extension cable is active or passive?

Could a USB power meter help?

---

**Edit:**

Other than cosmetics, is there a surefire way to test for the physical differences between active and passive cables?

Comment: Active USB A cables typically require external power input. So there you go! A “normal” looking USB A cable will not be active; they will be passive. Any USB A cable that is bulky looking and “odd” is most likely an active USB A cable.

Comment: What if a passive USB cable is designed to look bulky, as if it was active? Is there a way to test the cable, either through software or a power meter? @JakeGould

Comment: Or what if it's really an active cable but dead so it doesn't work?